# hide/Show Grid lines using a button D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a button which I have created using the Div element in my html file. This button is supposed to be linked to my d3.js file via the grid lines. In my JS file I have created supposedly user friendly horizontal and vertical grid lines which are supposed to guide the user position other visualization on the page and then be turned off after its used.

Problem is I'm new to JavaScript and D3 in general and I can't seem to figure out how to link my div buttons to my SVG created grid lines to create the hide/show effect even after sternly scrapping through stack over flow and google. I have tried different variations and ideas with no success.

Code for my button

```
 <body>
  <div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton" 
           type="button" 
           value="On/Off" 
           onclick="updateGrid()" 
           />

</div>
  </body>
```

code for my grid lines

```
var width  = 1500,
    height = 800,
    colors = d3.scale.category20();
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('oncontextmenu', 'return false;')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);
//vertical lines
Ver= svg.selectAll(".vline").data(d3.range(26)).enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
    return d * 80;
})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
    return d * 80;
})
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return 0;
})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return 800;
})
    .style("stroke", "#eee");

// horizontal lines

hor= svg.selectAll(".vline").data(d3.range(26)).enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return d * 60;
})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return d * 60;
})
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
    return 0;
})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
    return 1500;
})
    .style("stroke", "#eee");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve what you want.

My advice here is, since you're already using D3, don't call a function inline. Instead of that, use D3 itself to listen to the button click:

```
var toggle = true;
d3.select("input").on("click", function() {
      d3.selectAll("line").style("opacity", +(toggle = !toggle))
})
```

Here I'm simply toggling the opacity between `0` and `1`. In case you don't know (since you said you're new to JavaScript and D3), `+true` is `1` and `+false` is `0` (that's why I'm using the unary plus), and `!toggle` inverts the boolean.

Here is a demo, using your code with some minor changes:

```js
var width = 1500,
  height = 800,
  colors = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('oncontextmenu', 'return false;')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

//vertical lines
var ver = svg.selectAll(null).data(d3.range(26)).enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return d * 80;
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return d * 80;
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return 0;
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return 800;
  })
  .style("stroke", "#666")
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

// horizontal lines

var hor = svg.selectAll(null).data(d3.range(26)).enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return d * 60;
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return d * 60;
  })
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return 0;
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return 1500;
  })
  .style("stroke", "#666")
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

var toggle = true;

d3.select("input").on("click", function() {
  d3.selectAll("line").style("opacity", +(toggle = !toggle))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="option">
  <input name="updateButton" type="button" value="On/Off" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I wanted and the explanation helped a bunch in clearing out some of the mistakes I was making in my attempts.

Comment: chatGPT could not manage to provide working solution for toggling grid on and off. So I found it here :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope my code will help:

```js
// I add a div container instead of the <body> tag
var svg = d3.select("#container")
  .append('svg')
  .attr('oncontextmenu', 'return false;')
  .attr('width', 1500)
  .attr('height', 800)
  .style("border", "1px solid #ccc")

// initial
redraw("horizontal");

// I prefer 'd3.select("#option input").on("click", func)' style
function updateGrid(event){
    var btu = d3.select(event.target);

    if(btu.attr("value") === "On"){
        btu.attr("value", "Off");
        redraw("vertical");
    }else{
        btu.attr("value", "On");
        redraw("horizontal");
    }
}

function redraw(type){
    var data = d3.range(26), update, enter;
    // there are three stage of binding data: update, enter and exit.
    // But I just need to define two stage in your case.

    update = svg
            .selectAll("line")
            // all line to be marked with a specific value
            .data(data, function(d){ return d; });
    enter = update
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .attr({
                x1: 0, x2: 0,
                y1: 0, y2: 0,
                stroke: "black",
                "stroke-width": 1
            });
    
    if(type === "horizontal"){
        update
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr({
               x1: 0, x2: 1500,
               y1: function(d){ return d * 60; },
               y2: function(d){ return d * 60; } 
            })
    }else{
        update
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr({
               x1: function(d){ return d * 60; },
               x2: function(d){ return d * 60; },
               y1: 0, y2: 800 
            })
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton" type="button" value="On" onclick="updateGrid(event)"  />
</div>

<div id="container"></div>
```